# Passing a Tuple of Values through a Checkbox

Tags: python, html, django, checkbox, django-templates

I have a list of organized items that users may choose from using checkboxes. I am trying to pass a tuple of values for each checked checkbox so I can get information about the item itself and the group to which the item belongs. I have tried using hidden fields but it seems that the hidden field value is being passed regardless of if the corresponding checkbox has been checked or not.

If a checkbox is checked, I need the citation id and the parent software. Can I pass a tuple of (citation.id, sw) for each checked checkbox and, because multiple checkboxes can be checked, pass all of these together as a list of tuple? Like: [(citation1.id, sw1), (citation2.id, sw2), ] ? I need this info in my view.

Thank you for any help!

select_citations.html

```
{% for sw in software %}
    {{sw}}
    {% for citation in all_citations %}
        <input type="checkbox" name="myselection[]" value="{{citation.id}}">
        <input type="hidden" name="myselection[]" value="{{sw}}">
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I've also tried this but it doesn't seem to actually add/concatenate my values: `<input type="checkbox" name="myselection[]" value="{{ citation|add:sw }}">` and then, in my view: `mycitations = request.GET.getlist('myselection[]')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compose IDs of both models to a single value for the checkbox:

```
{% for sw in software %}
  {{sw}}
  {% for citation in all_citations %}
    <input type="checkbox" name="selection" value="{{citation.id}}-{{sw.id}}">
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

And then deconstruct this values in the view:

```
ids = [value.split('-') for value in request.POST.getlist('selection')]
```

Comment: That is exactly what I need @catavaran but it doesn't work...the values are not coming through. Even if I don't split the value, the list is still empty. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Do you send the form using the 'POST' method?  Is name of the checkbox input is the same as in the `getlist()` function?

Comment: Stupid naming mistake on my part, sorry about that. Thank you SO much @catavaran- it works!!